# Optimización de código

Tags: php, api, curl, revisión-de-código, optimización

Tengo una aplicación donde realizo un registro de usuario en una API, cuando un usuario se registra en mi página.
Mas adelante, si el usuario añade mas valores al registro o modifica alguno de los datos con los que se registró al principio, realizo un PUT en la API para actualizar estos nuevos datos.

Todas estas funcionalidades funcionan correctamente, pero me gustaría optimizar la clase que uso para conectarme en dicha API i hacer el POST i el PUT.

Actualmente tengo lo siguiente class, que la llamo des de la APP principal:

```
class connectSettings{

private $api_user = 'API_USER';
private $api_key = 'API_KEY';
private $resource = 'contact';



public function connectPUT($data_json, $contact){

    $ch = curl_init('https://'.$this->api_user.':'.$this->api_key.'@API_URL'.$contact);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_json);

    // Set HTTP Header for POST request
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_json))
    );

    // Submit the POST request
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    // Close cURL session handle
    curl_close($ch);

}

public function connectPUSH($data_json){

    $ch = curl_init('https://'.$this->api_user.':'.$this->api_key.'API_URL'.$this->resource.'/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_json);

    // Set HTTP Header for POST request
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_json))
    );

    // Submit the POST request
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    // Close cURL session handle
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

}

La function connectPUT actualiza los datos y la connectPUSH los añade al registrarse el usuario.
Como se puede ver las dos functions son casi identicas. Solamente cambia la línea de la conexión en la URL.

```
$ch = curl_init('https://'.$this->api_user.':'.$this->api_key.'@API_URL'.$contact);
```

Y en el connectPUT añado una linea de mas:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
```

Quiero optimizar las dos funciones en una, para no repetir todo el código, pero no consigo hacerlo correctamente.
He pensado en crear una variable por cada linea que se vaya a repetir y luego llamarla en cada función pero estamos en las mismas, no optimizo nada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifica tu función, agregando un parámetro, luego te quedara algo asi:

```
public function connectPUT($data_json, $contact, $update){

    if($update){
        $ch = curl_init('https://'.$this->api_user.':'.$this->api_key.'API_URL'.$this->resource.'/');
    }else{
        $ch = curl_init('https://'.$this->api_user.':'.$this->api_key.'@API_URL'.$contact);
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

    if($update){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_json);

    // Set HTTP Header for POST request
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_json))
    );

    // Submit the POST request
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    // Close cURL session handle
    curl_close($ch);

}
```

Se puede poner todo en el mismo bloque, pero lo he puesto separado para que se vea mejor.

Te paso a explicar tu duda.

En la clase principal tienes en alguna linea de codigo algo como: `connectPUSH($data)` ó `connectPUT($data, $contacto)`, que es donde invocas a la funcion.

Pues estas lineas tienes que modificarlas y poner: `connectPUT($data, $contacto, $update)`.

Ahora, si estas haciendo el registro, $contacto sera vacio (""), y update seria FALSE. Quedando asi: `connectPUT($data, "", false)`

En el otro caso quedaria asi: `connectPUT($data, $contacto, true)`

Si no quieres complicarte con otra variable, (`$update`), puedes hacer lo mismo que en el ejemplo de codigo, pero con el $contacto, es decir:

```
if ($contacto == ""){
  //...es nuevo registro
} else{ 
  //...es un update
}
```

Espero te sirva. Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder. Si me puedes aclarar donde declaras el $update  porfa? En la App principal y luego se lo paso o lo declarar en la misma class de la conexión?

Comment: `$update` es un parámetro del método, así que lo tienes que pasar al llamar. Según dices en tu pregunta:  "La function connectPUT actualiza los datos y la connectPUSH los añade[...]", así que antes de invocar al método que te ha puesto @srsole supongo que sabrás si lo que estás haciendo es PUT o PUSH. Si es lo primero, `$update = true` y si es lo segundo `$update = false`

Comment: Perfecto, justo lo estaba haciendo. Gracias a los dos por la aportación.